# convert text file into dictionary -Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am given a .txt file which looks like this..

2:rain
3:odd
5:yes
6:go

I need to convert it into a dictionary.

This is what I have done so far.

```
 words_dict = {}
 file = open(filename, "r")
 for word in file:
      k, v = word.split(":")
      words_dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()                
 file.close()
 return words_dict
```

However, when i go and print the dictionary it does not match my expected output of {2: 'rain', 3: 'odd', 5: 'yes', 6: 'go'}

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: {'2': 'rain'}
{'2': 'rain', '3': 'odd'}
{'5': 'yes', '2': 'rain', '3': 'odd'}
{'5': 'yes', '2': 'rain', '3': 'odd', '6': 'go'}
{'5': 'yes', '2': 'rain', '3': 'odd', '6': 'go'}
[]
{'5': [], '2': [], '3': [], '6': []}

Answer (score 0):

```
l="2:rain 3:odd 5:yes 6:go".split()
{x.split(":")[0]:x.split(":")[1]  for x in l}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_ = [x for x in open('text.txt').read().split()]

dict_ = {k: v for k, v in [x.split(':') for x in list_]}


# list_ = ['2:rain', '3:odd', '5:yes', '6:go']
# dict_ = {'2': 'rain', '3': 'odd', '5': 'yes', '6': 'go'}
```